# How to Resize image without loosing image quality in c++ or opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv

- I am working on one project and for that i need to scale up image.
- I have tried  **re size** function of OpenCv library for re sizing.But image quality is decreased.
- Suppose i have image of 136x136 size and i want to re size it to 209x209 with same quality.How can i do it?

Comment: what's "the same quality"? there will be pixels added if you increase size. This will introduce artifacts since you cant guess how the details should look like. You can try to use different interpolation methods, have a look at cv::resize documentation

Comment: I have already used cv::resize.But if any other method is there then i will be helpful for me.

Comment: use cv::resize but try a different interpolation method there. standard parameter is linear interpolation. see documentation what kind of different interpolation methods can be used in cv::resize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, there is no way to increase the size of your image and generate new information between the pixels. All resizing methods involve some kind of interpolation between the original information.

If you look at the [OpenCV documentation for the resize function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) you will see these options:

- INTER_NEAREST - a nearest-neighbor interpolation
- INTER_LINEAR - a bilinear interpolation (used by default)
- INTER_AREA - resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire’-free results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the INTER_NEAREST method.
- INTER_CUBIC - a bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood
- INTER_LANCZOS4 - a Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 pixel neighborhood

You may find that INTER_CUBIC or INTER_LANCZOS4 produce an image with higher "quality".

Comment: in special cases (e.g. pure black and pure white image), inter_nearest might be best because it wont introduce new colors (e.g. grayscale levels) to the image. But object borders will look more pixelized/blocklike.